# Selecting ::after after img with css selector

Tags: css

I want to select "::after" in an html structure like this.

```
<div class="test">
   <img src="test.jpg" class="lazy loaded">
   ::after
</div>
```

If there is a "loaded" class in the img tag, I want to hide ::after.

So something like;

```
img.loaded + ::after {
  display: none;
}
```

But there is no such selector, is there a way to select it using only css?

Comment: do you mean `img.loaded::after`?

Comment: Yes Ramon, but the "::after" here is not the after of the img. The after of ".test". That is: ".test::after".

I want to reach this after with a class in the img tag.

Comment: css can't select that, but with a bit of javascript you can still do this